# How do I select a cell range using the keyboard while editing a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

When your typing a formula, you can hit one of the arrow keys to select a cell with your keyboard:

[image]

That's nifty because you don't have to reach for your mouse to select a cell. However, while editing a function after you've already typed it out, you can't select a cell with your keyboard (I can understand if excel blocks out the left and right arrow keys because it'd then be confusing for the program to know whether I want to move the cursor within the active cell or whether I'm trying to move out of the cell to select a range -- but why block the up and down keys as well?)

So, when you're trying to edit a function, say, like here where I want to change the cell "D5" by clicking on a appropriate cell), you can't use your keyboard:

[image]

Any workarounds?

Comment: *when you're trying to edit a function, say, like here where I want to change the cell "D5" by clicking on a appropriate cell), you can't use your keyboard* ?? clear 'D5' symbols by backspace, then select another cell address using arrow keys, what's a problem?

Comment: That doesn't work. You can't select cells while editing even if you clear "D5" -- you'll either have to delete the whole cell (which can be cumbersome if a function is quite long and you only want to change one cell) or use the mouse to select the cells.

Comment: Oh! I understand it seems... you want to switch from "edit formula as a text" to "select cell as argument by arrows", is it? If so, I don't know the solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the cell containing the function (e.g. `SUM(E3,D5)` selected, press <kbd>F2</kbd>, which will put the cell in edit mode, with the caret at the end.

Move the caret with the arrow keys and select the reference you want to change, with <kbd>shift</kbd> and arrow keys (e.g. E3 selected).

Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to change to reference mode and use the arrow keys to move to the cell you want to refer to in the formula. Note that the formula is changing accordingly.

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the new formula.

Answer (score 0):

Use named ranges.   Instead of just picking cells as arguments to functions, create a named range with a meaningful name.   Press `Ctrl+F3` to get to the Name Manager Dialog box, New, and use the name 'Inventory', with a Refers to of E3:E5.   Then you can create your function =Sum(Inventory).   Later if you need to modify that range, go to the Name Manager Dialog box, select the row with the range you want to modify, press `Tab`, and you can reselect (or edit) the Refers to.

This has the added benefit of documenting your work.  Another person can see the formula =Sum(Inventory) and know what Inventory means in your business context without having to know where in the workbook it exists.

Keyboard way to just create a new named range: `Alt+M`, `M`, `D`